# Can I create instances of components with "new" keyword and use that in render() method?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Note: working solution below**

I am wondering if I can simply create new instances of React components in "code" using the "new" keyword, vs creating elements as pseudo-html (if that is the correct name). I'd like to know how to do this and if it's even possible? I am using the class syntax.

```
EG: var comp1 = new MyComponent({ title: "test 1" });
VS: <MyComponent title="test1" />
```

Example code:

```js
//MyComponent
import { Component } from "react";

export class MyComponent extends Component<any, {title: string}> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.title}</div>
  }
}

//App
import { Component, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import { MyComponent } from "./mycomponent";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  renderComponents = () => {
    // THIS IS WHAT I WANT, BUT DOES NOT WORK

    // var nodes: MyComponent[] = [];

    // var comp1 = new MyComponent({ title: "test 1" });
    // var comp2 = new MyComponent({ title: "test 2" });

    // nodes.push(comp1);
    // nodes.push(comp2);

    //This works
    var nodes:ReactElement[] = [];

    nodes.push(<MyComponent title="test1" />);
    nodes.push(<MyComponent title="test2" />);

    return nodes;
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.renderComponents()}</div>;
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Please note: I am fairly new to React and Typescript and did not write javascript in like 10 years.

The reason why I want to create instances of components using the "new" keyword is partly because I am familiar doing it like that and because I (think) that code will be cleaner that way, especially when combining/chaining more elements together. Personal preference...

I also am still learning about components, elements and such. I am not exactly sure why I can't return an array of MyComponent and why ReactElement (or ReactNode) works instead.

**Update2:**

Thank you all for your feedback. I am just curious about how things work and experimenting, and I need to RTFM (I did, but I am doing other work in between and forgot some basics).

Working code, for those who might have the same question:

```js
//mycomponent.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

export class MyComponent extends Component<any, { title: string }> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.title}</div>;
  }
}

//App.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Component, ReactElement } from "react";
import { MyComponent } from "./mycomponent";

export default class App extends Component {
  renderElements = () => {
    var elements: ReactElement[] = [];
    var element1 = React.createElement(MyComponent, { title: "Test1" }, null);
    var element2 = React.createElement(MyComponent, { title: "Test2" }, null);
    elements.push(element1);
    elements.push(element2);
    return elements;
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.renderElements()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: "*THIS IS WHAT I WANT*" - **why** do you want that? Is it about passing an object for the props?

Comment: A `Component` instance is not a `ReactElement`.

Comment: "*using the "new" keyword is partly because I am familiar doing it like that*" - false causality :-) "*I think that code will be cleaner that way*" - no, it won't. "*I also am still learning about [the difference between] components, elements and such [and] why [one] works [but not the other]*" - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/30971395/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40423841/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44825842/1048572 and https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html then

Comment: Yes; my colleagues will hate me (because you're right) :) But thanks though, very good feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, creating a new component instance is not the same as using JSX. Also, you would need to account for components being functions and not just classes.

JSX is syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement(MyComponent, props)`. So by not using JSX you are keeping React out of the process of creating and managing the component. This means no state, re-rendering, etc, and just won't work as needed.

You could use this verbose syntax yourself instead of JSX, but theses are your only two options.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, that makes sense! However, this code does not work (outputs nothing) in my .tsx file. Can you explain / show me how to get it right?

  renderComponents = () => {
    var nodes: ReactElement[] = [];
    var component = React.createElement(MyComponent, { title: "Test" }, null);
    nodes.push(component);
    return nodes;
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.renderComponents()}</div>;
  }

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you posted, are there console errors? More importantly, I don't really suggest taking this route. JSX is the standard. The function calls may look more natural to you in this simple example, but to any other React dev this will look foreign. Trying it out of curiosity is fine, but I would strongly advice against doing this as your permanent solution

Comment: I'm trying out of curiosity, just want to know how things work. I am sure that later down the line I won't be creating elements like that anymore. Just testing things out. It works!